# Semaphores not avoiding thread loss

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

this is my first question here so please bear with me.

I am currently working on a UNI assignment on multithreading and concurrency in Java where we are asked to implement various versions of a "Call Center" using different thread locking methods, with one of them being Semaphores. I'll get right into the code to show what my problem is:

**Producer Class:**

```
public final class Caller implements Runnable {
    private final CallCenter callCenter;

    public Caller(long id, CallCenter callCenter) {
        this.callCenter = callCenter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            callCenter.receive(new Call());
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Consumer Class:**

```
public final class Operator implements Runnable {
    private final CallCenter callCenter;
    private Call call;

    public Operator(CallCenter callCenter) {
        this.callCenter = callCenter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            this.call = callCenter.answer();
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    public Call getCall() {
        return this.call;
    }   
}
```

**Service:**

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public final class BoundedCallCenterSemaphore implements BoundedCallCenter {
    private final Queue<Call> pendingCalls = new LinkedList<Call>();
    private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(MAX_NUMBER_OF_PENDING_CALLS, true);

    public void receive(Call call) throws Exception {
        semaphore.acquire();
        pendingCalls.add(call);
    }

    public Call answer() throws InterruptedException {
        semaphore.release();
        return pendingCalls.poll();
    }
}
```

**Call Implementation:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public final class Call {
    private static final AtomicLong currentId = new AtomicLong();
    private final long id = currentId.getAndIncrement();

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer**

I know I am probably not using the semaphore the way it is intended to be used, but reading the official docs an other blogs/answers does not help at all.
We have the following constraints: **only modify the Service Class, solve using Semaphores and only use Semaphore.acquire() and Semaphore.receive() to avoid racing and busy waiting, no other method or thread-locking structure is allowed**

**Actual Problem:**

I'll avoid posting here the entirety of the tests written by our professor, just know that 100 calls are sent to the Service, for simplicity each caller only calls once and each operator only responds once. When implementing the callcenter without semaphores you'll get busy waits generated by a while loop and concurrency is not well-managed as some calls can be answered twice or more if the different threads act simultaneously. The mission here is to eliminate busy waits and ensure each call is received and answered only once. I tried using semaphores as reported above, and while busy wait is eliminated some of the calls end up not being answered at all. Any advice on what I am doing wrong? How do I ensure that each and every call is answered only once?

Comment: Since you configured the semaphore to allow multiple threads to succeed at `acquire()` at the same time, multiple threads may execute `pendingCalls.add(call)` *but `LinkedList` is not thread safe*. You have to replace it with a thread safe queue. If you use a `BlockingQueue` with a capacity matching the `MAX_NUMBER_OF_PENDING_CALLS`, you don’t need a semaphore at all as you can block the threads while putting (I’ve never seen a real life example where `Semaphore` is really useful). But you can use an unbound or concurrent queue together with the semaphore to fulfill your assignment.

Comment: Hey! First of all thank for your comment, nice to get a conversation going on here for the first time! Secondly, it is mandatory to use semaphore (I'll edit the requirements in the op). Third, the buffer must be bounded as the unbounded version is part of another exercise. Also, if I configured the semaphore to handle one thread at a time like `new Semaphore(1, true)` that won't work and I either get TimeOut or some calls are still not answered. Anyway i'll try with the concurrent queue: [This one?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) TYSM

Comment: NVM i just read from the docs that concurrent queue is unbounded, any other suggestion on a bounded - thread-safe buffer? @Holger

Comment: The first choice for a bounded buffer would be `ArrayBlockingQueue`, however, I don’t know whether its use would contradict the assignment “no other method or thread-locking structure is allowed”. As said, in principle, it could do the entire job without a semaphore. On the other hand, if your semaphore ensures that you never try to put more elements than its capacity, it would never block, hence, not be used as a “thread-locking structure”.

Comment: That is a pretty useful insight! I think I am gonna go ahead and use that without its blocking feature, that might not grant me a full grade but it sure is a handy solution! Honestly, implementing this without semamphores has been a lot easier so I guess the point of the assignment is figuring out just that! Thank you again for your informed responses mate, it really is nice to discuss this kind of stuff here! Have a good one @Holger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did it using three semaphores. The first semaphore `new Semaphore(MAX_NUMBER_OF_PENDING_CALLS, true)` guards the queue in the sense of blocking new entries when `pendingCalls.size() >= MAX_NUMBER_OF_PENDING_CALLS` . The second semaphore `new Semaphore(1, true)` guards the producer threads, allowing just one thread at a time to access the queue for adding operations. The third and last semaphore starts with no permits and waits for the first producer thread to insert the first call into the buffer `new Semaphore(0, true)` .

**Code**

```
public final class BoundedCallCenterSemaphore implements BoundedCallCenter {
    private final LinkedList<Call> pendingCalls = new LinkedList<Call>();
    static Semaphore receiver = new Semaphore(1, true);
    static Semaphore storage = new Semaphore(MAX_NUMBER_OF_PENDING_CALLS, true);
    static Semaphore operants = new Semaphore(0, true);

    public void receive(Call call) throws Exception {
        try {
            storage.acquire();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {

        }
        try {
            receiver.acquire();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {

        }
        synchronized (pendingCalls) {
            pendingCalls.add(call);
            operants.release();
        }
    }

    public Call answer() throws InterruptedException {
        try
        {
            operants.acquire();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {

        }
        Call call = null;
        synchronized (pendingCalls) {
            call = pendingCalls.poll();
            storage.release();
            receiver.release();
        }
        return call;
    }
}
```